# Sending Gmail email to "me"

Tags: gmail

In Gmail, those emails originating from me appear with the sender "me". But when I want to send email to myself and I put "me" in the address, Gmail doesn't recognize it.

I went so far as to create a "me" in "My Contacts" and I still cannot use "me" in the address (the `To` field).

Any way to work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to create a contact "me" which is then searched as you type "me" in the To: field when composing an email. You will then need to pick the appropriate "me" contact from the drop-down list of contacts that contain the characters "me". You can't simply type "me" in the To: field and expect it to be routed to *you*.

I have an "@ME" contact for the same reason. I prefix it with "@" so that it is at the top of my contacts list and no other *real* contacts contain the "@" character in their name - so the drop-down list is very short.

I have read that Gmail treats email that you send to yourself as duplicate(?) and consequently it does not appear in your Inbox - only in your Sent *folder*. Although this does not happen to me - it appears in my Inbox like any normal email.

**EDIT:** I have found that after closing and opening Gmail it will no longer prompt with the "me", "myself" or "@ME" contacts in the autocomplete dropdown when filling in the "To" field! This is bizarre. Changing the contact name in some way - such as adding a real name eg "@ME (Joe Bloggs)" resolves the issue temporarily, but it disappears again when returning to Gmail later. Contacts where I have used my full name (without any funny prefix) remain in the autocomplete dropdown.

Comment: I had that exact problem until this morning. If you add "@" in front of the contact listing for yourself ("@me" or "@myself"), like the other answer here suggests, Gmail will recognize it. It might also work using a different prefix. I don't know why Gmail won't auto-suggest "myself" as a contact.